# as3 if remove Parent Do all children get removed too?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, removechild, addchild

I am loading a mc called Spiri into a mc called Box. Later I want to remove both from memory usage and off screen. I have the off screen in a tween not shown here.

**If I use `removeChild(box);` will it also remove all Children with in?** 
Basically I am loading 3 movies from library with a function call. Then trying to remove them and call the same function multiple times. Which means the same movies are loaded again and again with the same names.  This IS SUPPOSED TO replace the old ones but maybe its not because I am not removing them properly because by the 10th or 15th call it is getting very slow.

I am also adding an event-listener in a function too. Is that then adding a some event-Listner every single time and taking up resources as well?

It seems to be very slow after several times running a that function which makes me believe something is not getting unloaded correctly.

```
//I tried 
box.removeChild(Spiri);
Spiri = null;
//then remove the parent like this
removeChild(box);  /// but this gets an error.
again if i just do this
removeChild(Spiri); // it makes me wondering if they are getting removed.
```

How what is the best way to remove parent and all children in an mc?

Comment: I suggest you check out Adobe Scout I believe it's still free for the time being and is an amazing tool for profiling and tuning performance.  It will monitor active SWF files on the computer or you can install Scout on a mobile device and profile AIR applications (very simple to setup).

Comment: @shaunhusain Agreed with the Adobe Scout. I can't imagine Flash development without it now, honestly. Such a fantastic application.

Comment: There's also some good stuff on here: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/quick-tip-understanding-garbage-collection-in-as3/ One more thing to check out is MrDoobs HiRes Stats https://github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats

Comment: @shaunhusain I actually built my own monitor that displayed in app like Hi-Res does. Monitored memory, frames per second, and even had a built in console. Plus it was light weight, completely mobile friendly (even adjusted for DPI changed) and didn't affect memory or FPS in any significant way. Then Adobe released Scout less than a month later. Definitely felt like I had wasted a few days at that point.

Comment: You can also just use the profiler that comes with Flash Builder...

Comment: @AmyBlankenship You can't use that profiler with release builds. Custom in-app ones you can and you can do it with Scout as well. Honestly, though, the Flash Builder profiler is a joke compared to Scout.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. The children are no longer located on the stage, but they are still children to the parent until `removeChild()` is called. That can be good and bad. Obviously, it is great for reusing objects but can be **terrible** for memory management because those objects can only be garbage collected when their parent is garbage collected. For a simple app, that is usually fine. But for something massive... not so much.

For the project I am working on now (a massive 30 page, 50,000 liner), I created a light-weight GUI framework to handle all of my DisplayObjects. Everything except basic `Bitmap` and `Shape` `DisplayObject`s extend a single class which extends `Sprite`. In that class, I have this function:

```
final public function destroy():void {
    this.removeAllEventListeners();

    var i:int, l:int, cur:DisplayObject;
    l = this.numChildren;

    for ( i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
        cur = this.getChildAt( i );

        if ( cur is XISprite && !this.stopChildXISpriteDestroy ) {
            ( cur as XISprite ).destroy();
        }
        else if ( cur is Sprite ) {
            ( cur as Sprite ).removeChildren();
        }

        if ( cur is Bitmap && ( cur as Bitmap ).bitmapData && !this.stopBitmapDestroy ) {
            ( cur as Bitmap ).bitmapData.dispose();
        }

        if ( cur is Loader && !this.stopLoaderDestroy ) {
            ( cur as Loader ).unload();
        }

        if ( cur is Shape ) {
            ( cur as Shape ).graphics.clear();
        }
    }

    cur = null;
    i = l = NaN;

    this.removeChildren();
}
```

It basically does a hard wipe of all the objects and allows me to easily qualify all children of that class for Garbage Collection. I also am keeping track of all event listeners so there is no chance at all a rogue listener could prevent GC (by calling `removeAllEventListeners()`). I also have some protected flags in the class that allow you to stop the destroy on a certain object type (so I can leave a SWF or an image loaded in memory if needed)

It might be overkill, but memory consumption has been an issue in this app and that function has really helped manage it. This may be more than you need, so you can just call `removeChildren()` with default params and it will remove all children from the parent object.

As an afterhthought: Keep your DisplayObjectContainers as simple as possible. Avoid nesting them as often as possible. The first conditional, where I call destroy on every single XISprite that is a child of an XISprite is *great* but it could be disastrous if there were loads and loads of XISprite children as the destroy() calls would pile up on each other and freeze the app.

Comment: Really like this answer, I had only been doing bitmapData.dispose() calls.  Does the graphics.clear() really help?  Also just FYI, though this shouldn't be a problem now the docs for Loader.unload() say: Prior to AIR 3.6, this method has no effect on iOS.

Comment: @shaunhusain Was not aware it had no effect on iOS pre-3.6. I've only been on 3.6 for the last few weeks so I figured I would have noticed by now. graphics.clear() dumps all of the vector data. So the vector itself is completely destroyed and removed from memory. Doesn't help garbage collection of the actual object, but that object is minuscule compared to the vector data.

Comment: I think the critical bit that's not emphasized enough in this is that you need to remove all listeners to the object you're removing and its children. The object may not be able to do that, because it might not know about listeners that have been added from elsewhere.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I actually keep a Vector of every event listener that is added to an object (simply be overriding `addEventListener`) and `removeAllEventListeneners()` loops through that and removes each, so my custom Sprite class doesn't have to worry about rogue listeners, but you are correct and that is generally what causes an object to not be garbage collected.

Comment: That only works if you either don't expose children (so that listeners could be added to them outside the parent's control) or you're the only coder on the project.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship No, it only works if every object that would normally extend Sprite extends my new Sprite class. I track **every** event listener that is added to any class that extends my Sprite class and remove them all manually when `removeAllEventListeners()` is called. Sure, children that don't extend that class are out of luck but in the end, 90% of our objects do extend it so it does its job incredibly well